# special characters as option arguments in sigils

Tags: elixir

In my progress of learning Elixir, I am trying to make a simple sigil to parse csv's.

I have managed to make a sigil to do this, however I cannot find a way to make it work with special characters, such as for example `;`.

```
defmodule CommaSigil do
  def sigil_v(lines, []), do: parse(lines,",")
  def sigil_v(lines, delimiter), do: parse(lines,"#{delimiter}")

  defp parse(lines, delimiter) do
    lines
    |> String.rstrip
    |> String.split("\n")
    |> Enum.map fn line ->
      String.split(line, delimiter)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Example do
  import CommaSigil

  def test do
    ~v"""
    hello,world,again
    1,2,3
    """
  end

  def test2 do
    ~v"""
    helloxworldxagain
    1x2x3
    """x
  end

  def test3 do
    ~v"""
    hello;world;again
    1;2;3
    """; # <-- Elixir does not care about the ';'
  end
end

Example.test
|> IO.inspect

Example.test2
|> IO.inspect

Example.test3
|> IO.inspect
```

**Can I escape the `;` character somehow, or is it not possible to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semi colon (`;`) plays a special role in Elixir - it is used for [delimiting multiple expressions](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#delimiters) on single line of code.  Hence, I don't think you can escape it. **In fact, you cannot use any of the Elixir special characters  as modifiers as it can potentially result in compilation error.**

Besides, Modifiers in sigils are kind of options for the logic of sigils.  For example, `i` is a modifier to do case-insensitive match in Regular expressions. Meaning of each modifier value is fixed for the given sigil's definition.

We should not use modifiers as a way to pass additional parameters to underlying sigil's function - as you are doing - using modifiers (`x`, and `;`) to specify the character that should be used as delimiter to split string.

**PS:**
Somewhat similar to the Sigil you have created, is available in Elixir - its called [Word List](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#word-lists) - it uses modifiers to indicate return types - delimiter for splitting words, however, is fixed - it is always a space character.

Comment: couldn't one argue the same for the case of `i` for regex sigils?.. ( that is, `i` is sort of a 'function parameter' for a regular expression)